# Irreducible quadratic factors; partial fraction decomposition.

Tags: quadratics, partial-fractions

Please help me understand why there is Dx+E, Fx+G etc, instead of the regular A's, B's, C's etc. What is it about the irreducible quadratic in the denominator that makes it different on top?

[image]

Comment: Actually you can do with with just powers of linear factors in the denominators and only constant coefficients in the numerators, but then you'd need complex numbers. Without complex numbers, many quadratics are irreducible and so can't be decomposed any further, and you need an extra $x$ up top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, recall that for $\dfrac{p(x)}{q(x)}$, the degree of $p(x)$ has to be less than $q(x)$ in order for us to apply partial fraction decomposition. It then follows that since the denominator has irreducible quadratic factors, the numerator can either have a constant term $D$ or it's also possible that the numerator has a linear term $Ex+F$. This is because the degree of the denominator is $2$, so the degree of the numerator can either be of degree $0$ (constant term) or degree $1$ (linear term).

Comment: It says in the book that the degree of P must be less than the degree of Q.

Comment: yes, sorry that's what I meant. Explanation is still valid for the rest of the post.

Comment: Thank you, can you help me with this please?http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/773479/partial-fraction-decomposition-of-a-complicated-rational-function

Comment: I guess my question is why do you use linear numerators when the denominator is irreducible?

Comment: @King Squirrel: It's possible that the numerator is either a constant or a linear term. You don't know for sure so you assume it is a linear term of the form $Ax+B$. If it is a linear term, then when you simplify the decomposition you will get some non-zero $A$. On the other hand, if it truly is a constant, then after your decomposition simplification, you will find that $A=0$. If this is the case, you will be left with $0\cdot A+B=B$, which is just a constant. But you assume $Ax+B$ as the numerator because you don't know whether it's a constant or a linear term right from the start.

Comment: So why isn't it possible that a reducible one doesn't have linear numerators?? I'm confused.

Comment: I mean why wouldn't you do this for the reducible ones too?

Comment: If you don't you are automatically assuming that the numerators are constants, but when they are irreducible you say they could be either constants or linear.