# Partial fraction decomposition of a complicated rational function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations, partial-fractions

Find the partial fraction decomposition of the rational function $\displaystyle \frac{2x^3+7x+5}{(x^2+x+2)(x^2+1)}$

I have tried dividing first but keep running into problem after problem, please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try writing your fraction as a sum of $\frac{A_0+A_1 x}{x^2+1}+\frac{B_0+B_1 x}{x^2+x+2}$ and then find $A_0,A_1$ and $B_0,B_1$ by equating $(A_0+A_1 x) (x^2+x+2)+(B_0+B_1 x)(x^2+1) = 2x^3+7x+5$

The final answer should be

$\frac{2x^3+7x+5}{(x^2+x+2)(x^2+1)}=\frac{5}{x^2+1}+\frac{2x-5}{2 + x + x^2}$

I hope that helps.

Comment: I equated these and multiplied both sides by the LCD and I got to a system that gives me wrong answers. Your answer is correct according to the book but I just can't solve this one! Please help me.

Comment: Collect the powers of $x$. You get: $(A_1+B_1)x^3+(A_0+A_1+B_0)x^2+(A_0+2A_1+B_1)x+(2A_0+B_0)$

Comment: Comparing the above to $2 x^3 + 7 x + 5$ you get the system:

Comment: $2 A_0 + B_0 = 5$, $(A_0 + 2 A_1 + B_1) = 7$, $(A_0 + A_1 + B_0) = 0$, $(A_1 + B_1) = 2$, this system has the unique solution $A_0=5,A_1=0,B_0=-5,B_1=2$, which is the answer I gave

Comment: Ok I must be doing the system wrong. Can you help me out with understanding why we can assume that reducible ones will have constant numerators but with irreducible ones the numerator can either be linear or constant??

Comment: I guess the simplest way to see the difference between reducible and irreducible factors is to realise that over the complex field the irreducible factors are actually reducible and hence a term with a quadratic irreducible factor in the denominator can be written as a sum of two terms with constant numerators and linear denominators. Now if you add this terms back to obtain a real expression the linear terms will combine to give you a linear numerator.

Comment: That makes some sense, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1**: Find $a, b, c, d$ such that:  $\dfrac{2x^3 + 7x + 5}{(x^2 + x + 2)(x^2 + 1)} = \dfrac{ax + b}{x^2 + x + 2} + \dfrac{cx + d}{x^2 + 1}$

**Step 2:** Rewrite:
 $\dfrac{ax + b}{x^2 + x + 2} + \dfrac{cx+d}{x^2 + 1} = \dfrac{1}{2}\cdot \dfrac{a(2x+1)}{x^2 + x + 2} + \dfrac{1}{2}\cdot\dfrac{2b - a}{(x + \frac{1}{2})^2 + (\frac{\sqrt{7}}{2})^2} + \dfrac{c}{2}\cdot \dfrac{2x}{x^2 + 1} + d\cdot\dfrac{1}{x^2+1}$.

**Step 3:** Make the right substitution and complete answer.

Comment: Why is it that when the denominators are irreducible you make the numerators linear and not constant?