# Partial Fraction Decomposition for Laplace Transform

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform, partial-fractions

As part of trying to solve a differential equation using Laplace transforms, I have the fraction $\frac{-10s}{(s^2+2)(s^2+1)}$ which I am trying to perform partial fraction decomposition on so that I can do a inverse Laplace transform.  When I try to work out this fraction, I get that $-10=0(A+B)$ since $s^1$ does not show up in the fraction.  How does partial fraction decomposition work for a fraction like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should work on the following, instead:

$$\frac{As+B}{s^2+2}+\frac{Cs+D}{s^2+1}$$

Or use the [convolution theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_theorem).

Comment: Thank you, I can't believe I forgot about that.  It's been about a year since I last did partial fractions.

Comment: @ChrisCrutchfield: Thanks! I am I could help you. :-)

Answer (score 0):

$\dfrac{-10s}{(s^2+2)(s^2+1)}=\dfrac{10s}{s^2+2}-\dfrac{10s}{s^2+1}$

Beacuse

$$\dfrac{-10s}{(s^2+2)(s^2+1)}=\frac{As+B}{s^2+2}+\frac{Cs+D}{s^2+1}$$

then

$$(A+C)s^3+(B+D)s^2+(A+2C)s+(B+2D)=-10s$$

$A+C=0$

$B+D=0$

$A+2C=-10$

$B+2D=0$

imply $A=10$, $B=0$, $C=-10$ and $D=0$.

Comment: Would you be able to explain where that comes from?

Comment: are irreducible quadratics in the denominator

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/773442/irreducible-quadratic-factors-partial-fraction-decomposition